# OS X - delegate method equivalent to textShouldBeginEditing

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I am new to OSX programming.

I would like to do a very simple app with the purpose of learning. The app is a NSTextView and a label.

The idea is for the label to show the character count of the textview.

Looking at NSTextView delegate methods, I don't manage to see which method is called every time a character is typed. Something like textField's textShouldBeginEditing.

How do I do that?

Comment: osx is richer than ios, use binding, no need to code.

Comment: like I said, I am learning OSX. No need to code? That seems magical. Care to tell me how?

Comment: I dont have mac now, i will try tomorrow.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver :self
                                        selector:@selector(myTextChanged:)
                                            name:NSTextDidChangeNotification
                                          object:nil];
}


-(void)myTextChanged:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    [textfieldLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ld",[textField.string length]];
}
```